# Why e.Handled = true not working?

Tags: c#, wpf, routed-events

I have following XAML

```
 <StackPanel MouseEnter="StackPanel_MouseEnter" Height="130" Background="Blue">
    <Grid MouseEnter="Grid_MouseEnter" Height="60" Background="Red" >
       <Button MouseEnter="Button_MouseEnter" Height="20"/>
    </Grid>
 </StackPanel>
```

In code behind I am doing this

```
private void StackPanel_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{

}

private void Grid_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
}

private void Button_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{   
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Now even if I move mouse over `Button` and set `e.Handled = true`, the events of `Grid` and `StackPanel` are called respectively. Why? What should I do to stop routed event from bubbling up?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The MouseEnter event is not a bubbling event, it is a direct event (like classic CLR events). From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.mouseenter%28v=vs.95%29.aspx):

> You can define multiple MouseEnter
>   events for objects in XAML content.
>   However, if a child object and its
>   parent object both define a MouseEnter
>   event, the parent object's MouseEnter
>   event occurs before the child object's
>   MouseEnter event. This is not a case
>   of a bubbling event; it indicates only
>   that the mouse (or stylus) has entered
>   both objects, potentially at different
>   times depending on the layout and the
>   composition of the visual tree.

So you can't prevent it from being fired on the parents. You can use the [IsMouseDirectlyOver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.ismousedirectlyover.aspx) property to see if the mouse is in fact only over the given element though.

Comment: Regarding the proposal in your username, I second the motion!